# How can I securely hide a file using the .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I found many articles regarding encyrpt/decrypt (secure) files using C#. But apart from that, I also want to hide those files from explorer. Means, it should not be viewable by user. Only application can restore that files using secure key that we used for encryption.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your title and tags say "delete", but your question itself talks about encrypting and hiding files. Which do you actually want to do?

Comment: I think he means "hide" not "delete"

Comment: Yes, I mean "Hide" not "Delete". Is this possible using C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fully "hide" files from Explorer, the only way to achieve it is by writing a [File System Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885434.aspx) (which could also be used for encrypting them).  It cannot be done in managed code.

Comment: Will writing a File System Filter hide it also from 3rd party applications (like 3rd party File Explorer)?

Comment: Yes, a FSF can hide it from anything/everything.  You could even make it so only your app could open it and only after providing a key.

Comment: Can I use Dokan library for writing a File System Filter in C# to hide all files/folders?

Comment: I doubt it.  Looks like Dokan is for Windows, not CE.